# putting tefillin on diabetics with continual glucose intradermal probe inserted

Tags: tefilin, handedness

For diabetics with a continual glucose intradermal probe inserted, can tefillin be put on the right arm even though the person is right-handed as the probe does not allow the Shel Yad to be put on correctly?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question might get closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: It will be important to explain to the rav what area of the biceps remains uncovered, if any, as one can sometimes place the tefilin on the left arm, in an uncovered area, without a blessing (Nishmat Avraham)

Comment: The answer to your question is definitely no, the tefillin has to be on the correct arm. But there's still potentially an interesting question of what to do in this case, but it's hard for anyone to answer since we don't necessarily know what this medical device looks like or where it blocks.

Comment: Right handed people put tefillin on the left hand

Comment: @Efraym the question in this case is what to do if the left arm is not "available" because o the medical device covering part/all the area

Comment: The unit is the size of a cell phone as it transmits signal with blood glucose levels every 5 minutes to the hospital via wifi.

Comment: Don't those go on the belly and clip onto your belt? Why would you have it on an arm muscle?

Comment: You are describing an insulin infusion pump,not a continuous glucose monitor

Comment: And it goes on the bicep? (P.s. Since I am not OP, I won't be notified of responses unless you tag me with the @).